# Descending order with compress option of the cite package

Tags: bibtex, citing, cite-package

I'm loading the [cite package](https://ctan.org/pkg/cite?lang=en) for my project. Is there any simple way to change the order of numbers within the compressed version of the citaions in the output?

The default behaivior of the `cite` package for compressing citations is  in ascending order, for example [1-5] or [2-12], but I want vise versa, for example [12-2] or [5-1]. How can I do that?

Comment: Please give a use case for wanting to reverse the endpoints of a compressed sequence of numeric-style citation call-outs. E.g., should the bibliographic entries in the references section also be listed in descending rather than ascending order, by whatever sorting criterion is applicable, e.g., alphabetical sorting by authors' surnames, or sorting by first mention of a given piece in the body of the document?

Comment: @Mico It's very obvious when you use a RTL language in your project, you read and write from right to left, then a descending order from right to left for example in [5-1] makes sense for these type of projects. It's not just one example, but this is a sufficient to explain why I need such an order. I believe it's not necessary for me to sort _bibitems_ in a descending order simultaneously (maybe it is another question), but in my case, I need only to change the order of two numbers in the compressed version for the output. I'm looking for a straightforward way to do that.